# Prove By Induction that this inequality is true.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the following by induction.

(1 + q)^n  ≥ 1 + nq, where q is a real number greater than -1.

I know the induction steps.

1. Show n = 1 satisfies it
2. induction hypothesis: Assume this property is true
3. Prove that n+1 satisfies the property.

How do I prove this?

Please help. Thanks!

Edit: I fixed it. Sorry for the confusion it was a typo.

Comment: $(1+x)^n \ge 1+nq$ then $(1+x)^{n+1} = (1+x)^n(1+x)\ge (1+nx)(1+x) = 1+nx + x + nx^2=1+(n+1)x + nx^2\ge 1+(n+1)x$.

Comment: What is $q$ compared to $x$? Obviously if $q >\frac {(1+x^n)-1}n$ it is false.

Comment: $q$ makes not sense.  It's obviosly *not* true that $(1+x)^n > 1+ n*10^{100}$

Comment: I really think you wrote the problem down wrong.  If it's supposed to be true for all $x, q,n$ that's obviously false.  If its supposed to be that there is *some* $q$ it is true for that is trivially true.

Comment: A google is more than a zillion.  And this has to be true for *all* $x$.  Some $x$s are *less* than a zillion.

Comment: I fixed the question.

Comment: My first comment holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $q > -1$ then $1+q > 0$ and so if $(1+q)^n \ge 1+nq$ then $(1+q)^n(1+q) > (1+nq)(1+q)$.